# Android: Does a bitmap created by my app have to be stored and scanned before I can pass it as an implicit intent to other apps?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-bitmap, android-implicit-intent

**Introduction and background**

Hi, I have a bitmap created by my application, I wish for this bitmap to be sent to any apps that can handle the mime type "image/png" and the action ("ACTION_SEND"). Basically, allow the bitmap image to be sent to someone by another component like email and messaging etc.

**What I got now**

At moment my app saves the bitmap image to external memory within a directory I made. Each bitmap saved is scanned by the MediaScannerConnection and using the OnScanCompleteListener, I use the obtained Uri to build the implicit intent. This works fine.

**My question**

I am trying to cater for users who do not have external memory or have the setting ticked where they do not want any images saved/stored (just for that instance and gone when they close the app). **So do I need to actually save an image in memory and get a Uri in order to pass a bitmap image as a implicit intent.**

Many thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you dont need to save that image anywhere. Just get the filepath from the `Bitmap`:

```
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap,"abcd", null);
```

then get a valid `Uri` from it:

```
Uri image = Uri.parse(path);
```

and add this `Uri` to your `Intent` like this:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  image);
```

Done!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I am trying it now. Will let you know.

Comment: Hi, this seems to still save the picture in storage. It stores it in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera.

Comment: the `bitmap` is stored in memory, but you dont have to store it there, the OS does that for you :)

Comment: So is there any way I can have it where nothing is saved in internal or external storage. The only way I think I can do it is if I delete the image when its done because I have a path

Comment: yes that can be done ... you can call `startActivityForResult()` and after the `ACTION_SEND` is done, you can delete the image at the path location